# Composer clones GIT Commit instead of Tag

Tags: git, github, composer-php

I've forked a github project and want to switch into my branch.
I've added the repositories entry to my forked github project and composer starts
cloning the package.

```
Installing antibodies-online/omnipay-vr-payment (1.1.0): Cloning 7df29fad5d
```

Next I check if the origin is my new fork:

```
git remote -v

Output:
composer        https://github.com/DemigodCode/omnipay-vr-payment (fetch)
composer        https://github.com/DemigodCode/omnipay-vr-payment (push)
origin  https://github.com/DemigodCode/omnipay-vr-payment (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/DemigodCode/omnipay-vr-payment (push)
```

Thats okay and my fork. Now I want to list all available branches:

```
git branch -a

Output:
* (no branch)
  master
  remotes/composer/2DS20
  remotes/composer/master
  remotes/origin/2DS20
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

I'm missing the 2DS20 branch without remotes/origin.

If I now want to switch to 2DS20:

```
git checkout 2DS20
error: pathspec '2DS20' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I have no clue, what happens here? On another server it works totally fine. Any Ideas?

On the other server when I run git status, the following will be printed:

```
# On Tag v1.1.0.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

On my machine:

```
# Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With older versions of git, you have to be more explicit about the starting point.

```
git checkout -b 2DS20 origin/2DS20
```

The [`git checkout` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_description) explains the newer, more convenient behavior.

> ### `git checkout [<branch>]`
>
> … If `<branch>` is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it `<remote>`) with a matching name and `--no-guess` is not specified, treat as equivalent to
>
> ```
> $ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For all others facing that problem:

Git 1.7.1 was installed on our machine. The other one runs with 2.11.x. Updated to 2.22.0 and all works fine!
We're now able to type

```
git checkout my-branch
```

And it works like I expect it to work.